# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error, Although I did not have unique validation to any of my model properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a student model like below, where each student can subscribe to the same test

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const StudentSubscriptionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: Date,
    expireDate: Date,
    status: String,
    subscriptionId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'subscriptions'
    }
});

const StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    account: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    testSubscriptions: [{
        test: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'tests'
        },
        subscription: StudentSubscriptionSchema
    }],
    noteSubscriptions: [{
        note: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'notes'
        },
        subscription: StudentSubscriptionSchema
    }],
    testHistory: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'testhistory'
    }]
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('students', StudentSchema);
```

Whenever I'm trying to add the same test _id to multiple students test subscriptions it is taking only one record to only one student, for the next student, it's throwing a duplicate key error

```
check error MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: xyzcollection.students index: testSubscriptions.test_1 dup key: { testSubscriptions.test: ObjectId('60bce0a7a28bec57b8c84f2c') }
```

Below is the method I'm trying to push the test subscription

```
const reqBody = {
        test: req.body.testId,
        subscription: {
            date: req.body.subscriptionDate,
            subscriptionId: req.body.subscriptionId,
            expireDate: req.body.getExpiryDate
        }
    };

student = await STUDENT.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
            {
                $push: { testSubscriptions: reqBody }
            }, {
            new: true,
            runValidators: true
        });
```

Comment: What `db.students.getIndexes()` tells you when you run it mongo shell?

Comment: I figured out the issue, @AlexBlex yes there is an index issue fixed it by adding autoIndex: false to my student schema.

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB document "_id" field is reserved and by default is unique per document per collection even you have not defined explicitly to be unique  in your code ( when the collection is created , the unique index on _id field is automatically created by the mongod process ) ...